# Bukkit Right Click on Block

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

When I right click a block with a block on my hand, and the block on my hand didn't place, bukkit returns action `RIGHT_CLICK_AIR`, and will cause an error when I call `getClickedBlock()`.
How can I get the block I clicked?

This is a short viedo for demonstration:
http://youtu.be/0OVpu7X1-0U

Comment: I've got the same problem. Have you found an answer better than @gyurix'? Sure it would fix the problem, but it's more like a workaroud than a fix :/

Answer (score 1):

If Bukkit returns `RIGHT_CLICK_AIR` you didn´t click to the block, you only clicked to the air. So in that case the clicked block is the air and `getClickedBlock()` method returns null. If you want to know, with which item or block did you clicked, you can use the `event.getPlayer().getItemInHand()` method.

Comment: You're right. I tested it also, and I watched your video and really.

Answer (score 1):

I found a tricky method for it:

```
player.getEyeLocation().add(player.getEyeLocation().getDirection()).getBlock();
```

Comment: That will work but it will work when player have no distance with the block.BTW can this be consider as a bug?

Comment: It will only work in that case, so only if Bukkit returns RIGHT_CLICK_AIR and you clicked on a block.